# React gives me red underline errors but there is no error

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

Visual Code gives errors in lines but there are no errors in those lines.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please rename your file to "todo.jsx".

**Explanation:**

VSCode and other IDEs choose your parser based on the file extension. For VSCode it looks like you are creating a "normal" JavaScript file. But JavaScript does not know tags, so you get an error message.

*A small addition:* if you ever work with TypeScript in React, the same applies: instead of the .ts extension you should choose the .tsx extension.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your file is named `ToDO.js`. Since you're using JSX syntax, the file should be given a `.jsx` extension, so that VSCode knows how its syntax should be parsed (and, as a result, what errors to display).

So, rename it to `ToDO.jsx`.